Why is my Apache2 redirect www to HTTPS not working as expected?

Server Ubuntu 22.04
apache2 -v 2.4.52

Website alias for this question: example.com
I have configured and enabled my virtual host sites-enabled example.conf file as shown below. Default is disabled.
My site has no .htaccess file. When I go example.com in the browser, site launches and SSL checks okay (padlock). When I go http://example.com, site launches and SSL checks okay (padlock).
However, when I go www.example.com, the site launches but SSL fails (shows site insecure, padlock red). I thought I set up the redirect properly in example.conf but I guess I am missing something.
Please review my config file below and suggest changes to or trouble shooting method to help me get this problem sorted out.
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example  
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>


If you are absolutely positive you issued the certificate with both variants, like this for example:
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /home/example/public_html/ --domain example.com --domain www.example.com

Then try splitting your configuration per port, because as stated before the second VirtualHost block is probably ignored in your sample, and mixing the ports/protocols is not a good idea.
My paths/logs are not identical to yours but it gives you a good idea of the structure:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    CustomLog /home/example/logs/redirect80.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
    ErrorLog /home/example/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/example/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

If you also want to redirect a variant to another while using SSL, you can add this in an .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

